# Problem solving (numerically) the Tolman-Oppenheimer-Volkov (TOV) equations for any equation of state

Tags: thermodynamics, nuclear-physics, computational-physics, software, neutron-stars

I've been working on a code to solve the TOV equations for a while and recently I've got it right but only for one specific equation of state, the bag model, wich is not what I need since it should run for any hadronic equation of state. The code has given only wrong results for any EoS other than the bag model and I've tried evertyhing I could think of but nothing has made it so that the final diagrams for other EoS are correct. I'll put the code and some of the wrong results for some of the EoS I've been studying bellow.

```
    import math
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from scipy.integrate import odeint
    from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline
    from scipy.interpolate import interp1d





    pi = math.pi
    km2_gevfm3 = (1/(1.3234*10**(-6)))*0.001
    gevfm3_km = 1/(km2_gevfm3)
    B = 7.424*10**(-5) 
    cm = 1/1.4760



    eos = np.genfromtxt("C:\\Users\\felip\\Desktop\\TOV\\Equações de estado\\PtableTM1.dat") 
    eden, p = (gevfm3_km*eos[:,0])/1000, (gevfm3_km*eos[:,1])/1000 
    press = interp1d(eden, p, kind = 'cubic', bounds_error = False, fill_value = 'extrapolate') 
    #press = UnivariateSpline(eden, p, k = 5, s = 5)  
    dpde = press._spline.derivative(nu = 1) 
    #dpde = press.derivative(n = 1)  


    def TOV(y, r):
         eden, M = float(y[0]), float(y[1])
         dedr = -(1*(dpde(eden))**(-1))*((M*eden)/(r**2))*(1+press(eden)/eden)*(1+(4*pi*press(eden)*r**(3))/(M))*((1-((2*M)/r))**(-1)) 
        dMdr = 4*pi*eden*(r**2) 
        return [dedr, dMdr] 



    r0 = 10**(-10)
    rm = 5000  #km
    N = 1000
    rn = np.linspace(r0, rm, N) 


    emin, emax =   7.7*10e-15, 0.0003
    h_e = 1000
    e_range = np.linspace(emin, emax, h_e) 
    R,M,E =[],[],[]

    for e0 in e_range:
        M0 = (4*pi*e0*r0**(3))/3 
        contorno = [e0, M0]
        soltov = odeint(TOV, contorno, rn, atol = 10e-10, rtol = 10e-14, mxstep=5000)
        rmax = r0 
        mmax = M0
        esol = soltov[:,0]
        psol = press(esol)  
        k=0
for i in psol[:-1]:
    h=rn[k+1]-rn[k] + r0
    rmax = rmax + h
    mmax = soltov[k,1] 
    k=k+1 
    if i <= 10e-6:
            break 
R.append(rmax)
M.append(mmax*cm)
E.append(e0*km2_gevfm3)


    immax = np.argmax(M)
    Mmax = M[immax]
    Rmax = R[immax]





    f1 = plt.figure()
    ax1 = f1.add_subplot(111)
    ax1.title.set_text('M x E')
    ax1.set_xlabel('$(\epsilon)_c [GeV/fm^3]$')
    ax1.set_ylabel('$M [M_\odot]$')    
    ax1.plot(E,M,'-',color='blue')
    ax1.legend()

    f2 = plt.figure()
    ax2 = f2.add_subplot(111)
    ax2.title.set_text('M x R')
    ax2.set_xlabel('$R [Km]$')
    ax2.set_ylabel('$M [M_\odot]$')    
    ax2.plot(R,M,'-',color='red')
    ax2.legend()
    plt.show()
```

I couldn't get the ident right but it is correct on my code. I have no idea what could be changed here and I've gone through every line in this code and cant figure out why it shouldn't work for other EoS. For the BPS EoS, the results are:

[image: Mass x central energy density for BPS EoS]

[image]

I would apreciate if anyone could help me.

Comment: This looks like a question better suited for the [Computational Science site](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about debugging specific code, not physics. For questions about algorithms, consider asking a less code-specific version at [scicomp.SE].

Answer (score 2):

Since I do not have the equation of state (EOS) file used in the question I can not give an answer for the specific EOS but I modified the code to work with a tabulated EOS I had laying around. The problem lies in the radial grid used for `odeint`: with `rm = 5000 #km` and `N=1000` the output of `odeint` is spaced on a 5 km grid. When using a realistic EOS for neutron stars with reasonable input values for the central pressure/density this is way to coarse. `N` needs to be increased and or `rm` needs to be decreased to increase the resolution in radial direction.

I would however recommend switching to a more efficient way to compute the required radial points and to determine the stellar surface. I modified the code by introducing `TOVstep` and `TOVsol`. `TOVstep` evolves the equation from `r` to `dr` and if the solution has an energy density which is smaller than a threshold `dr` is reduced. `TOVsol` computes successive steps using `TOVstep` until the stellar surface is reached. For some reason OP has chosen an implementation in enclosed mass $M(r)$ and energy density $\rho(r)$ instead of enclosed mass and pressure $P(r)$. The surface(-radius) $R$ of a neutron star in the present context is defined by $P(R)=0$ which does not necessarily correspond to $\rho(R)=0$. $\rho(R)$ depends on the EOS used and in the following code I use the first tabulated value for the EOS I used.

Here an example computation (using the code below) for the [HS(DD2) EOS](https://compose.obspm.fr/eos/2), which includes a crust and electrons. The code works over a large range of densities and radii. In the mass over radius and mass over central density plots

> [image: MR]
>
> [image: Mrhoc]

we can identify three stable branches: neutron stars at high densities, white dwarfs (unphysical masses but typical radii), and self bound planets (at extremely low densities).

The following code is just a lockup and should probably be thoroughly tested before using it for serious computations this includes especially the involved (numerical) parameters.

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d


# constants
pi = math.pi
c0         = 299792458   # Speed of light in vacuum [ms-1]
G          = 6.67408e-11  # Newtonian constant of gravitation [m3kg-1s-2]
qe         = 1.6021766208e-19  # Elementary charge [C]

#sun
MSkg = 1.9884e+30;        # Solar mass [kg]
MSkm = MSkg*G/pow(c0,2)*1e-3;  # Solar mass [km/MS] = 1.47657

# CGS conversion factors
cdyncm2km2 = G/pow(c0,4)*1e5   # Conversion factor [km-2/dyncm-2)] = 8.26245e-40
cgcm3km2   = G/pow(c0,2)*1e9   # Conversion factor [km-2/gcm-3)] = 7.42592e-19

#Geometrized Units conversion factors
cfm3km3    = 1e54             # Conversion factor [km-3/(fm-3)] = 1e+54
cMeVkm     = G*qe/pow(c0,4)*1e3    # Conversion factor [km/MeV] = 1.32379e-60
cMeVfm3km2 = cMeVkm*cfm3km3   # Conversion factor [km-2/(MeVfm-3)] = 1.32379e-06


eos = np.genfromtxt("eos_HSDD2.d", skip_header=9) 
eden, p = (cgcm3km2*eos[:,2]), (cdyncm2km2*eos[:,3]) 
press = interp1d(eden, p, kind = 'cubic', bounds_error = False, fill_value = 'extrapolate') 
dpde = press._spline.derivative(nu = 1) 
eden_min=eden[0]


def TOV(y, r):
    eden, M = float(y[0]), float(y[1])
    dedr = -(1*(dpde(eden))**(-1))*((M*eden)/(r**2))*(1+press(eden)/eden)*(1+(4*pi*press(eden)*r**(3))/(M))*((1-((2*M)/r))**(-1)) 
    dMdr = 4*pi*eden*(r**2) 
    return [dedr, dMdr] 

def TOVstep(y,r,dr0,drth=1.0E-1,emin=eden_min):
    dr=dr0
    sol=odeint(TOV, y, [r,r+dr], atol = 10e-10, rtol = 10e-10, mxstep=5000)
    while (sol[1,0]<=emin) & (dr>=drth):
        dr=0.5*dr
        sol=odeint(TOV, y, [r,r+dr], atol = 10e-10, rtol = 10e-10, mxstep=5000)
    if (dr<drth) | (sol[1,0]<emin):
        return [r+dr,-1,sol[1,0],sol[1,1]]
        
    return [r+dr,dr,sol[1,0],sol[1,1]]

def TOVsol(e0,dr0=5.0,drth=1.0E-2,r0=1E-10,emin=eden_min,rmax=5.0E3):
    M0 = (4*pi*e0*r0**(3))/3
    dr=dr0
    r=r0
    sol=[r0,dr,e0,M0]
    while (dr>0.0) & (r<rmax):
        sol=TOVstep([sol[2],sol[3]],r,dr,drth)
        #print(sol)
        r=sol[0]
        dr=sol[1]
    return [e0,(press(e0)).min(),sol[0],sol[3],sol[2]]

emin, emax =  -22, 0
h_e = 400
e_range = 2.5E3*cMeVfm3km2*np.exp(np.linspace(emin, emax, h_e))
sols=[] 
for e0 in e_range:
    sol=TOVsol(e0)
    print(sol)
    sols.append(sol)

sols=np.array(sols)

f1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = f1.add_subplot(111)
ax1.title.set_text('$M(R)$')
ax1.set_xlabel('$R \\,[\\mathrm{km}]$')
ax1.set_ylabel('$M \\,[M_\odot]$')    
ax1.plot(sols[:,2],sols[:,3]/MSkm,'-',color='blue')
ax1.set_xscale('log')
ax1.set_xlim([5E0,1E4])

plt.savefig('mR.png', dpi=150)

f2 = plt.figure()
ax2 = f2.add_subplot(111)
ax2.title.set_text('$M(\\rho_c)$')
ax2.set_xlabel('$\\rho_c \\,[\\mathrm{MeV}\\mathrm{fm}^{-3}]$')
ax2.set_ylabel('$M \\,[M_\odot]$')    
ax2.plot(sols[:,0]/cMeVfm3km2,sols[:,3]/MSkm,'-',color='blue')
ax2.set_xscale('log')
ax2.invert_xaxis()

plt.savefig('mrho.png', dpi=150)
```

The code and the specific EOS file used can be found in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/MJSteil/46a196db6ab8b617ed7e7f416176da8b).

Comment: It didn't really work for the EoS's I've been trying to use. I should have linked them to the question. In this link I've uploaded every EoS that I should be able to use in a code and get valid solutions. Also, I should've said that not only the shape of the curves are very weird but also that the values are wrong EXCEPT for the bag model EoS. The link to the EoS is : [EoS](https://github.com/Heyden-Flores/EoS). I'm not sure that the same code should be able to solve for all of them without to many changes but that is kind of my goal. Thanks  !

Comment: I am sorry but all the tables are in a different format and not one has labels for the columns and just by looking at them the units are different. When working with such tabulated data meta data has to be included in some form or the files become absolutely useless. Include headers or separate files for meta data: source, column headers and units are a minimum in my opinion. This does not seem like a code problem to me but to be frank sloppy data management.